# Go back to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-framelayout

Btw this is my second fragment. This will appear once i press a button in a first fragment. In this fragment, if i press the back button on my phone, it will go back to previous fragment. Need your help guys. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ListAllDoctorFragment extends Fragment {
    Button close;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listalldoctor, container,false);

        close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                SHIT f2 = new SHIT();
                ft.add(R.id.content_frame, f2);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }


        });

        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: what?where?when?how?why?

Comment: i have a fragment with button inside and when i press it, this fragment will display. everything works but when i press back button, it doesnt back to the previous fragment. @RandykaYudhistira

Comment: To go for previous fragment just call `popBackStack()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to go to previous fragment, if that is the case, remove `ft.addToBackStack(null);` from your code.

Comment: still not going back to previous fragment